# Calculating Number of Sets for Different Types of Caches

Tags: caching

This is the basic understanding that I have so far for caches:

For direct-mapped caches, there is exactly one "line" or one "block" per set.

For a fully associative cache, there is exactly 1 set which contains all the blocks or lines.

For a n-way associative cache, there is exactly n lines or n blocks per set.

My question is, how do I go about calculating the number of sets given the total cache size and the block size? Is it just the cache size / block size? Is there a general formula that can be used for all types of caches to calculate this?

Comment: I don't think you can do that calculation, or I'm misunderstanding the question…  any caches' set associativity is baked into the hardware design and can vary independently of total cache size as well bock size

Comment: i mean im working on a school project to simulate caches in which i am given the total cache size, the block size, and the type of associativity

Comment: I'm confused by your use of terminology; AFAIK, the number of sets is determined by the associativity type, the cache/block sizes don't matter.  if you're told the associativity then you know the sets and the constraints that govern them.  I'm not an expert on this, so maybe if you added some more detail to the question somebody else would answer